# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected (SQLSERVER 2017)

Tags: sql, sql-server

This sentence:

```
delete cobis..ad_pro_rol
where  pr_producto = @w_producto and pr_rol in (select ro_rol from #roles)
```

Generate the next error en SQLSERVER 2017:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected

But only in one instance of SQL Server, we have four additional instance of SQL Server where this error is not present

Why it happens? What is the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the entire error message - all of it. Most likely you have a delete trigger that is not written correctly to handle multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
delete cobis..ad_pro_rol
    where pr_producto = @w_producto and
          pr_rol in (select ro_rol from #roles);
```

should not generate that error.  You may want to terminate the statement with a semi-colon, just to be doubly sure that no subsequent code is invoked.

Assuming that you are calling no other code, then look to see if `ad_pro_rol` as a `delete` trigger.  If so, the trigger may be at fault.

Comment: Good Morning and thanks for your answer. I reviewed the table "ad_pro_rol" and it doesn't have triggers